# Como fazer um menu lateral que se expande empurrando o body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

No estilo similar ao desse site aqui: [LINK](http://hyperakt.com/)

Comment: Qual sua dificuldade, estas a testar algum código ?

Comment: É que, tecnicamente, na estrutura html o menu estaria dentro do body. Então, como faria para empurrar o body se ele está contido dentro do body?

Comment: Vou tentar fazê-lo. Queria apenas saber se tem outras formas. Pensei em um código javascript aqui e vou por em prática,

Comment: O body é o elemento onde vai o conteúdo que será exibido, não tem "outro elemento" que fique ao lado dele pra "empurrar" o body. O que geralmente se faz é usar, dentro do body, um div lateral que pode ficar oculto, o restante do corpo em um outro div alinhado ao lado. Quando o div com o meu é exibido, ele naturalmente vai deslocar o outro div pra direita, simples assim.

Comment: Seria algo assim? https://jsfiddle.net/p2wvyafo/

Comment: Tente começar e surgindo uma necessidade mais específica posta aqui